# jmeter Saop/xml request Not accepting Json data in array of objects

Tags: jmeter

I am passing Json request in array of objects by doing Parameterization in soap/Xml Request sampler.
But while running the test plan it is not Reading Data from Csv file in array.

Is there any solution for this . Or we have to add any sampler and write java code to read data from csv file in Array of Objects??

[CSV File snippest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN59U.png)

[Request JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n71g8.png)

Waiting for all ur thoughts and inputs.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Most likely you're using CSV Data Set Config incorrectly
- Definitely you're using wrong Sampler

  1. Configure your CSV Data Set Config as follows:

     [image: CSV Data Set Config]
  2. Replace SOAP Sampler with [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, switch to "Body Data" tab and paste your parametrized request body there like:

     [image: HTTP Request]
  3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header with the value of `application/json`

Comment: Thanks alot ..as you said it is working as expected :)